# Cache-Money: Only use in Production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I use the [cache-money](http://github.com/nkallen/cache-money) gem for transparent usage of Memcached. Using the supplied config file it is enabled on all modes (development, test, production). Is there a way to only activate cache-money in production mode?

It's not immediately clear how to do this, and it's a total pain dealing with caching in development mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [Obie Fernandez](http://obiefernandez.com/) for a great offline hint: Stub out cache-money's #index method to do nothing. This provides a place for the #index statements in the models to go, and stops the error mentioned above.

Here is my full cache_money.rb lib:

```
if RAILS_ENV != 'development'
  require 'cache_money'

  config = YAML.load(IO.read(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "config", "memcached.yml")))[RAILS_ENV]
  $memcache = MemCache.new(config)
  $memcache.servers = config['servers']

  $local = Cash::Local.new($memcache)
  $lock = Cash::Lock.new($memcache)
  $cache = Cash::Transactional.new($local, $lock)

  class ActiveRecord::Base
    is_cached :repository => $cache
  end
else
  # If we're in development mode, we don't want to
  # deal with cacheing oddities, so let's overrite
  # cache-money's #index method to do nothing...
  class ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.index(*args)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

By turning off cache-money in test you can't know if its interfering with your code.

I did this instead:

```
require 'cache_money'
require 'memcache'

if RAILS_ENV == 'test'
  $memcache = Cash::Mock.new
else
  config = YAML.load(IO.read(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "config", "memcached.yml")))[RAILS_ENV]
  $memcache = MemCache.new(config)
  $memcache.servers = config['servers']
end

$local = Cash::Local.new($memcache)
$lock = Cash::Lock.new($memcache)
$cache = Cash::Transactional.new($local, $lock)

class ActiveRecord::Base
  is_cached :repository => $cache
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initializer, skip initialization if you're running in development mode:

```
unless 'development' == RAILS_ENV
  require 'cache_money'
  ....
```

Comment: I wish it was that easy. When cache-money isn't loaded, my indexed models fail to load:

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1963:in `method_missing_without_paginate': undefined method `index' for #<Class:0x20215b4> (NoMethodError)

Comment: Could you set the TTL option to zero in development?  That way it wouldn't save the cached result?